# How to Prevent inserting attachment for a custom object based on Parent record condition?

Tags: apex, attachment

I need to Prevent inserting attachment if parent record's status is "Closed". I have tried with before insert where i couldn't get parentid so it is not working. Any directions/suggestions will greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to Prevent Upload a file in notes & attachment for a custom object?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/288989/is-there-any-way-to-prevent-upload-a-file-in-notes-attachment-for-a-custom-obj)

Comment: Hi Renato, Similar to that question only. but as Frank said in the question, Not able to prevent attachment while inserting. I have tried with that code. The problem is we cannot get Parentid before insert. How to do that?

Comment: What do you mean? For content documents the related entity Id is on the `ContentDocumentLink` entity, in the `LinkedEntityId` field.

Comment: Ok should i write Trigger on ContentDocumentLink? I am wring trigger on contentDocument Object.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Trigger on ContentDocumentLink object which is related to your Parent record using LinkedEntityId field. You may try to use `addError` method on SObject to prevent DML operation from occurring, but I'm not sure other records (ContentDocument and ContentVersion) won't be created. If they will, you may throw a custom exception with a meaningful message.